# Different composition for training and test sets

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification

Training and test sets in machine learning, are normally discussed as though they will have the same composition, e.g. take X% of your examples as the training set, and the rest are the test set.

However, suppose you are trying to solve a classification problem - for simplicity, say binary classification, like distinguishing between photographs of horses and zebras. The classes are not equally common. Say 95% of photos are horses and the other 5% are zebras. If you feed that mix into a neural network, or any other machine learning algorithm, it will quickly settle on classifying everything as a horse and thereby achieving 95% accuracy.

There are such things as cost-sensitive neural networks, that can penalize a false negative more heavily than a false positive. But the added complexity increases development time and creates more opportunities for bugs to creep in.

A simpler, more general method is resampling, where you train the network on equal quantities of each class. If you have 10,000 pictures, take 250 zebra pictures, combined with 250 horse pictures, use that as your training set. The other 250 zebras can go with another 4,750 horses to form your test set. That way, you can calculate a confusion matrix on the test set that will reflect the performance that can be expected of the train network in the wild.

This means the training set and test set have deliberately different composition.

So my question: is it indeed normal for training set and test set to have different composition, and this just isn't often mentioned? Or am I missing something?